# How to move function from route in controller?

Tags: php, laravel

I made a function search by a tutorial, but the function was included in routes, and I need to add this function to my controller.I made this, but now, when I search, it returns me a blank page.

Here is my view:

```
<form action="/search" method="POST" role="search">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="q"
            placeholder="Search content"> <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
            </button>
        </span>
    </div>
</form>
```

And here is my route now :

```
Route::get('topic/{category?}/{page?}', 'CategoryController@category');
Route::any ( '/search', 'CategoryController@search');
```

Here is my function

```
public function search()
    {
      function () {
             $q = Input::get ( 'q' );
             $user = Opinion::where ( 'subject', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%' )->orWhere ( 'user_id', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%' )->get ();
              if (count ( $user ) > 0)
                  return view ( 'category-search' )->withDetails ( $user )->withQuery ( $q );
              else
                  return view ( 'category-search' )->withMessage ( 'No Details found. Try to search again !' );
        } ;
    }
```

*My category-search view:*

```
@extends('layout.template')

@section('content')
<title>Search results</title>


<div class="container">
    @if(isset($details))
        <p> The Search results for your query <b> {{ $query }} </b> are :</p>
    <h2>Sample Content details</h2>
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>User id</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach($details as $user)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$user->subject}}</td>
                <td>{{$user->user_id}}</td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
    @endif
</div>

 @stop
```

**Here is my first route with function:**

```
Route::any ( '/search', function () {
        $q = Input::get ( 'q' );
        $category  = Category::with('event','news','opinion')->where('category_url', '=' ,$category_data)->firstOrFail();
        $data['title'] = $category->category;
        $user = Opinion::where ( 'subject', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%' )->orWhere ( 'user_id', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%' )->get ();
        if (count ( $user ) > 0)
          return view ( 'category-search' )->withDetails ( $user )->withQuery ( $q );
        else
          return view ( 'category-search' )->withMessage ( 'No Details found. Try to search again !' );
} );
```

Comment: What is showing in your console after loading the page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

remove function () {

```
function search() {
    $q = Input::get ( 'q' );

        $category  = Category::with('event','news','opinion')->where('category_url', '=' ,$category_data)->firstOrFail();

        $data['title'] = $category->category;
    $user = Opinion::where ( 'subject', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%' )->orWhere ( 'user_id', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%' )->get ();
    if (count ( $user ) > 0)
        return view ( 'category-search' )->withDetails ( $user )->withQuery ( $q );
    else
        return view ( 'category-search' )->withMessage ( 'No Details found. Try to search again !' );
} );
}
```

Comment: and add error_reporting(E_ALL), maybe it get more info

Comment: Hey.Thank you, but I need to transfer that function in `public function search()` from my controller. The search function is working with my old route ( who included function(), but I need to transfer that function in my controller.

Comment: remove ```function () {``` from ```public function search()
 {
  
  function () {
    $q = Input::get ( 'q' );```

Comment: Yes, that was the correct answer :) I will accept your answer soon.

Answer (score 1):

your search method must be like the below:

```
public function search(){
$q = Input::get ( 'q' );
$user = Opinion::where ( 'subject', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%' )->orWhere ( 'user_id', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%' )->get ();

if (count ( $user ) > 0) {
    return view ( 'category-search' )->withDetails ( $user )->withQuery ( $q );
}else{
    return view ( 'category-search' )->withMessage ( 'No Details found. Try to search again !' );
}}
```